# Typescript add only some type parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I would like to do this:

```
function foo<A, K extends keyof A>(a: A, key: K): A[K] {
    return a[key];
}

foo<Type>({ key: 'value' }, 'key');
```

But this doesn't work because ts requires all or none of generic types to be explicitly typed.

My workaround:

```
function bar<A>() {
    return {
        foo<K extends keyof A>(a: A, key: K): A[K] {
            return a[key];
        },
    };
}

bar<Type>().foo({ key: 'value' }, 'key');
```

Here the `K` type is implicit.

Now my question is, have any of you had the same problem and how did you solve it?

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242

I found this proposal on github which would make type parameters optional if possible. This has been open for a while though, in the mean time I'd still like to know your workarounds.

Comment: how about `foo<Type, keyof Type>({ key: 'value' }, 'key');`? [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8BBANIg0ogUwA8oCwATAZ0QGsCBPOYRDAPgAoBDALhZzvq9cASl4YA2rgC6iAN4AoREsQAnAlBAqkncQKkBueQF958qPQAOBRABVL1gLxzFyVL0pQVMMAHNjpiARKOAAbAgA6ELgfdhR0Oyt+BiZbew5ZVzheAHIAI04VbMQjHGy47OFhQ1MgA)

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you don't need to write `Type`, typescript will try to infer the type of `A`, like

```js
function foo<A, K extends keyof A>(a: A, key: K): A[K] {
    return a[key];
}

foo( { key: "value" }, "key" );

interface Bar {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address: string;
}

const bar: Bar = {
    name: "tim",
    age: 18,
    address: ""
};

// It can also get the correct type
foo( bar, "name" );
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8BBANIg0ogUwA8oCwATAZ0QGsCBPOYRDAPgAoBDALhZzvq9cASl4YA2rgC6iAN4BYAFCIViAE4EoINUk7iBUgNxKAvkqUo47ObQa8ARADdOAGxAF7iEznsDPw40UlGDBSNWBOCAJEACFONTklVUQwTgBbAl5KKDUQgHNA5M48zJSQNIAjAjVC1U5ycg1KSiyc-MCzIMUIBGzECvjeOISAXkTlVVSMh1g0+ywkupLeAEYADgWJlXrGgmaHe1NApQB6E8QASShECE5dF0o4RBLrqAALaJ61DWhEKHoAA4ECyoawDNQ+KYeRABIA)